# If $M = P \oplus Q$ then is $M\cap N = (P \cap N) \oplus (Q \cap N)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, direct-sum

> (1) If $M,N,P,Q$ are $R$-modules and $M = P \oplus Q$ then is $M\cap N = (P \cap N) \oplus (Q \cap N)?$

Since the modules are not said to be anything like finitely generated or free, I really don't have any idea regarding this one .

> (2) So if this expression can be proved to be false is it true when $M$ is said to be free or finitely generated?

Thanks in  advance for help!

Comment: No. Hint: Think about diagonals when $P$ and $Q$ are isomorphic.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft 'diagonals' ? I don't get what you're trying to suggest?

Comment: The diagonal in a direct sum of two copies of the same thing is the set of elements of the form $(x,x)$.

Comment: Are you sure you want $Q\cap M$ not $Q\cap N$?

Comment: @user10354138 Yeah, thanks! that was a typo. I've corrected it.

Comment: The short answer is that this already fails with $M=\Bbb R^2$: in fact, most subspaces have trivial intersections with $\Bbb Re_1$ and $\Bbb Re_2$.

Comment: Oh my God, no. Since when are all the $\Bbb R$-s equal?

Comment: @SaucyO'Path $\Bbb R^2 = \Bbb Re_1 \oplus \Bbb Re_2$. Then as TobiasKildetoft suggested, considering the subspace $\{(x,x):x \in \Bbb R\}$ has trivial intersection with both $\Bbb R e_1$ and $\Bbb R e_2$.

Comment: That is better.

Comment: Thanks for helping by posting useful comments everyone. If anyone would post it as an answer then I could accept that answer and complete the discussion .